# How to upload images faster on iOS, when using takePictureAsync?

Tags: ios, react-native

We have an app, created with React Native, where the user can take a picture and save it to his account. So we are sending the photo to our server. The problem is, that this takes really much time (about 20 to 30 seconds) on iOS. With the Android-Build it is much faster (about 2 seconds).

We have tried to reduce the quality of the pictures, but that has also not a big effect.

```
takePicture = async function(camera) {

  const options = {
    quality: 0.5,
    fixOrientation: true,
    forceUpOrientation: true
  };

  const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(options);

  this.props.onCapture(data);

};
```

We would like to achieve the same uploading-time like on Android. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

I've written the following function. After taking image it returns the original and resized image which takes around 500KB on iOS.
It uses [ImagePicker](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-image-picker) package.

```
const pickImage = async (index) => {
const { status: cameraPerm } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
const { status: cameraRollPerm } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);

import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'
if (cameraPerm === "granted" && cameraRollPerm === "granted") {
        let pickerResult;
        if (index == 0 || index == undefined) {
            pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({ allowsEditing: false, aspect: [4, 3], quality: 1 });
        }
        else if (index == 1) {
            pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({ allowsEditing: false, aspect: [4, 3], quality: 1 });
        }
        if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
            let resizedImage = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
                pickerResult.uri, [{ resize: { width: 1200 } }],
                { compress: 1, format: "jpg", base64: false });
            return [resizedImage.uri, pickerResult.uri];
        } else {
            return
        }
    } else {
        alert(Messages.userManagement.cameraPermissions);
        return
    }
```

Then you can call above method like this.

```
let [resizedImage, originalImage] = await pickImage();
```